# How to disable sort in React table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table, columnsorting

Disable sorting for a particular column is not working, I have used the method from documentation
https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy

```
export const COLUMNS = [
    {
        Header: 'Avatar',
        accessor: 'avatar',
        maxWidth: 50,
        minWidth: 50,
    Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) => (
      <img
        src={value}
        width={60}
      />
    )


    },
    {
        Header: 'Name',
        accessor: 'name', 
        Filter:ColumnFilter,
        disableSortBy:'true'
        

    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using string value:

`disableSortBy: 'true'`

You should use boolean value instead:

`disableSortBy: true`

Answer (score 0):

With TanStack v8, you have `enableSorting: false,` now in the columnHelper.accessor that does the job